# Comment « rat » et « loup » ont-ils évolué pour signifier « manquer » ?

Tags: étymologie

> [rater](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/rater#.C3.89tymologie) : (Date à préciser) Dénominal de *rat*<sup>[[1]](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/rater#cite_note-TLFi-1)</sup> et -*er*, dérivé de l'expression *prendre un rat* (« ne pas lâcher son coup, avoir des ratés ») → voir [louper](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/louper#fr) fait sur *loup*.

[Ce livre](https://books.google.com/books?id=UV8Gtnf5iCwC&pg=PA427&lpg=PA427&dq=%22prendre+un+rat%22&source=bl&ots=9aUxkoJA-R&sig=PwIZdL-IvYngG9z6wV6fihjxg5A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CFEQ6AEwCDgKahUKEwitxZ7upILIAhWDooAKHesEDvc#v=onepage&q=%22prendre%20un%20rat%22&f=false) (découvert avec Google) associe le rat à un anathème, laquelle association s'applique aussi au loup.  Mais je ne vois pas comment rapprocher l'acception ultérieure de « manquer » à partir des acceptions originales.

1. Pourquoi l'expression *prendre un rat* signifie-t-elle « ne pas lâcher son coup » ?
2. Cette définition peut-elle être approfondie ? Quels sont les changements sémantiques dissimulés ou manquants ?

Comment: Douze lignes au-dessus de votre référence, il faut convertir 'rat petit' (rat de petite taille, formule inusitée) en *petit rat [de l'Opéra]*

Comment: Je n'ai pas répondu sur louper dont le seul rapport avec rater est la synonymie, et visiblement tu le sais. Ça peut faire l'objet d'une autre question/réponse. *Louper* vient de  *loupe* (une pièce qui comporte un défaut, un travail mal fait). Étymologie incertaine (rien à voir avec le loup l'animal), [voir le TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/loupe) 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Prendre un rat* (pas utilisé de nos jours) se disait d'une arme à feu qui s'est enrayée et dont le coup ne part pas. On emploie plus volontiers de nos jours *avoir des ratés*.
Les étymologistes renvoient l'emploi de « prendre un rat/rater » à l'analogie au bruit que fait l'arme qui s'enraye (*rat rat rat*). Pour certains c'est un bruit semblable à [celui du rat qui ronge](http://wordhistories.com/2012/06/27/verbes-dandys-snobs/), pour d'autres c'est par imitation du bruit du piège à rat qui se referme sur l'animal ([p.465](http://persee.fr/web/revues/home/prescript/article/anami_0003-4398_1922_num_34_135_8217?_Prescripts_Search_tabs1=standard&)). Le *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française* cite Guiraud : « d'après l'ancien français *raster, rater* (→ ratisser) « racler, ronger » le rouet du mousquet puis le chien du fusil grattant sans réussir à tirer d'étincelle. »